# Php login error - Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, mysqli

I looked at previos Undefined error questions to see if I could find help for my question, but I can't seem to fix it for my problem. 
So when I try to log in a user I get an error that says Undefined index:
No sure why Im getting this message on my login.php page

I have a database and a table called users with data inserted

this is what I use to connect to the database

conn.php

```
 <?php
   session_start(); 
   $dbhost = "127.0.0.1"; // my database 
   $dbname = "fxdme";
   $dbuser = "root";
   $dbpass = "";

   $mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " .     mysqli_error("Cant Connect"));

  ?>
```

the login script

login.php

```
<?php include 'template/header.php';?>

 <form  action="login.php" method="POST">
  User Name: <input type="text" name="username" />
   Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
   <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In"/>
 </form>    


<?php  

$result=$mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "' .
$_POST['username'] . '" AND password = "' . $_POST['password'] . '"');

//set session user 
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];

if ($_SESSION['user_id']) {    
   echo "You are logged in, $session_username. <a href='logout.php'>Log out</a>"; } 
else {
   echo " cant log in";
} 
?>
```

// Index page

My index page
index.php

```
//in the template header is where Im calling my conn file 
 <?php include 'template/header.php'; ?>

 <?php  
 if (isset($_GET['invalid'])) {         
  echo "<tr><td colspan='2' align='right'>Invalid login.</td></tr>";    
 }  
 ?>
```

Im trying to get the error fixed so I'm not worried about sql injections at the moment. I    just want to be able to login and and worry about the other stuff later.

Comment: are you checking if you there a POST on the page before querying the db? ex :(if(isset($_POST["login"])))

Comment: what index is undefined?

Comment: Post a copy of the exact error thrown.

Comment: Hey @JRSofty this is the exact error thrown, Notice: Undefined index: username in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ArturoLuna_Final/login.php on line 19. line 19 is where $results starts

Answer (score 4):

You will find that `$_POST["username"]` will return invalid index if username is not in the post variables.

I usually create a set of variables to hold the my post variables so I can do validation and normalisation of the data first

So before your query statement

```
$username=(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : "";
$password=(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["password"] : "";
```

then use $username and $password in your query.  You could event turn the previous statements into a function call passing in the variable name to check.

```
function getPostVar($name) {
   return (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : "";
}

$username=getPostVar("username");
$password=getPostVar("password");
```

Obviously your code is ripe for sql injection with at username of `' union select * from users --`

Comment: ...and it looks like the OP is storing unhashed passwords. +1

Comment: On a side note, it's not really necessary to check if $_POST array is set. It'll always be set, unless someone does unset($_POST). In which case checking isset($_POST['key']) will return false with no warning.

Comment: Wasn't 100% certain if isset(array(key)) would warn or not and just put the sanity safe version incase someone used this function for other arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There is not anything in your code to make a query string in URL to fetch by `$_GET`. How can you have an index when you don't have anything ?

For what you said, you must use a `header('location:index.php?invalid=1');` if the user can not log in to your system.

Comment: Whilst that is a bug, because of using isset it won't be the specific bug reported

Answer (score -1):

Might not be the same issue for you but I had this same error when converting to mysqli and my fetch statement looked the same as yours.

try changing.

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

to

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```